# Screen reattach: Cannot open your terminal

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I am trying to use screen with another user than I logged in. The command is started with:

```
sudo -u user /usr/bin/screen -A -m -d -S screen ./nice_command
```

For reattaching I am using `screen -x screen`, but it always says:

> There is no screen to be attached matching screen

What is my mistake?

EDIT:

```
screen -x user/22969.screen
There is a screen on:
        22969.screen       (12/13/2011 11:37:43 PM)        (Private)
```

Comment: Do a `screen -ls` to see which screen sockets you have and what their names are.

Comment: I got following output `No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-root.
`.

Answer (score 6):

Since you did `su -u user` to get a screen session it now belongs to `user`. 
You need to do `sudo -u user screen -x screen` to attach to it.

Or specify the path to it ( `screen -x user/[pid].screen` ) if the screen is in multiuser mode and you have access to it. `screen -ls user/` will give you info on sessions for `user`.

For multiuser screen to work you need to have it enabled <kbd>ctrl+a</kbd>`:multiuser on` and add users <kbd>ctrl+a</kbd>`:acladd root` (or other user). This is done from within screen.
Screen also needs to be setuid `chmod u+s $(which screen)` and screen sockets dir must be readable. (This is almost always the case already).

(good guide here: http://aperiodic.net/screen/multiuser )

Comment: It seems that the screen is private and that is the reason why I can't reattach it (see above).

Comment: I edited my post to include info about multiuser screen sessions.

Comment: Thanks, there is a missing spell in *multiuser*. Is there any possibility to do that over a shell script or anything like that?

Comment: Put multiuser and acladd lines in the config file .screenrc.  I found a good guide here: http://aperiodic.net/screen/multiuser